# Cout << Smart Pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique, cout

I've been following CodeBeauty's tutorial on C++ pointers, and I've come across a problem on the [video regarding smart pointers](https://youtu.be/e2LMAgoqY_k).

```
unique_ptr<int>unPtr1=make_unique<int>(25);
cout << unPtr1;
```

I did include `<memory>`, and my syntax is exactly the same as shown, but I get this error message whenever I try to run the program (full error is [here](https://pastebin.com/e9cKGPCB)):

```
pointers.cpp: In function 'int main()':
pointers.cpp:194:22: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'std::unique_ptr<int>')
                 cout << unPtr1;
                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

Could this be a compiler issue? I'm working in VSCode + mingw-64.

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: What do you want to print: the address stored by the smart pointer or the value at that address?

Comment: _`cout << unPtr1;`_ is probably a typo. Should be either `cout << unPtr1.get();` or `cout << *unPtr1;`, depending on address or value should be printed.

Comment: @GonenI I'm surprised you don't get an error. As far as I know there's no `operator<<` for `unique_ptr` in the standard library. What implementation are you using?

Comment: Don't use cout. cout is a failed experiment.

Comment: @KeithThompson VS2017  basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Out, const unique_ptr<_Yty, _Dx>& _Px)

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that you are trying to use an `operator<<` that takes a `std::ostream` on the left and a `std::unique_ptr` on the right, but the compiler cannot find such an operator.

Such an `operator<<` was [added in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_ltlt).

The presenter in the video is using Visual Studio.  C++20 support was [added in Visual Studio 2019 v16.9 and finalized in v16.11](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/).  But even Visual Studio 2017 apparently also defined an `operator<<` for `std::unique_ptr`, at least for C++14 and C++17. It is not a far stretch to assume she is compiling with a modern version of Visual Studio, which would explain why the example compiled fine for her.

So, make sure that you are using a version of mingw-64 that supports the C++20 standard, *AND* that you instruct it to actually use that standard during compiling.

Otherwise, you can simply replace `cout << unPtr1;` with `cout << unPtr1.get();` to get the same result.

Comment: @GonenI Thanks, I added the info to my answer.